# How can I fix or prevent getting holes in my jeans near the crotch?

Tags: sewing

I am a male and I get a hole in the crotch of my jeans all the time. It happens in about 6-12 months of owning the jeans. It always happens in the same spot. I have tried many different brands now and it happens to all of them. What is causing this? What can I do to prevent it? How do I fix it if it already has holes?

Comment: What kind of 'hole'? Is the fabric totally gone on that spot, or is there a seam that doesn't hold two pieces of fabric together? Or both?

Comment: A hole in the fabric next to a seam. It is not the actual seam splitting

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your title slightly to focus on your question and getting a solution to your problem. I'm not sure if this is on topic as it's not really about crafts, more about standard wear and tear on clothing.

Comment: Do you ride a bicycle? If so, that might do the damage. Changing to a recumbent bike did take away the source of damage for me and my jeans have not suffered in the crotch section anymore. Less dramatic might be changing the seat to one that is kinder to the jeans.

Comment: Is it one hole, or two symmetrical holes? A lot of people get holes in their jeans where their thighs rub together.

Comment: You might want to add any skills or equipment you have that would enable you to mend a fabric like denim. That way people will be able to offer you better advice on fixing your jeans.

Comment: I have noted similar damage patterns in the brand of jeans I buy.  I tend to walk about 10 miles per week (part of the daily commute) and this results in ruining a pair of £40 "Marks and Spencer" jeans in something like 18 months.  The damage pattern is absolutely consistent and really annoying.  That said, I also get through a pair of "Karrimor" brand shoes in about 2 years.  Nothing lasts these days and the prices only go up!  Good for you, for seeking to repair your garments rather than replacing them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely caused by the friction of your inner thighs rubbing together causing the material to wear in that spot quicker (especially because there are a few seams right there).

This can also be exacerbated by wearing pants that are too tight so that it's relatively tight around the upper leg or ones you shrunk by washing in hot water and running them in a dryer. If you're going to dry them you should wash them in cold water and dry them on low to minimize shrinkage. I have shrunk great jeans before and had to get rid of them because I made them too small. Finding a different pant cut may alleviate this, however, this will probably happen to any jean if you wear and wash them too much so if you can have more pairs of jeans and wash them a bit less they'll probably last a little longer, but it's pretty much always going to happen eventually.

You *could* fix them by sewing a jean patch on (cut up a different pair of jeans or buy a patch from the store) but you have to remember you're going to add more seams and a patch of jean that's either a different color or older/newer jean material and it probably is not going to last all that long.

Comment: If you're going to sew a patch, you could also do that at the inside, so it's less visible on the  outside.

Comment: @JiUgug - Yes, but that still means you're attaching something adding more seams and putting something older on something newer or vice versa which means it's not going to wear evenly anymore though he might not care about that anyways since he's asking.

Answer (score 2):

As an engineer, I’d suggest reenforcing that specific area.

You can get an **iron-on patch** and cut a shape out of it, and apply that to the **inside**. That way it won’t show any extra seams.

You can also do that with military-grade duck tape (like Gorilla  brand) which will survive many washings, but is meant to be put on temporarily.

Since it breaks adjecent to the seam, I think it’s not friction/wear like some have suggested, but is too tight there.  Some motions will stretch the faberic more than it can handle and damage accumulates.  Where it was sewn is actually weaker, and the join can cause stresses to concentrate in that location.

So, make that specific spot more resistant to being pulled open.

Comment: I cannot recommend any of the suggested solutions! I once tried an iron-on patch on the inside of the crotch area and it rendered the pants unwearable. The patch doesn't stick well at the edges and causes friction on sensitive skin (I can only imagine what Duct Tape would feel like). The patch makes the material in that area twice as thick and the pants unbelivably uncomfortable. The glue cannot withstand constant movement and after one washing cycle the patch fell half off and added more damage to the pants.

Answer (score 2):

Is it okay to offer up a brand of jeans that you may want to try? There is a **company*** in the US that manufactures jeans that feature a gusseted crotch, they are well made and last years.

Darning is one of the best ways to repair denim. You can do this by hand or machine; with or without a patch. Same way you darn socks or holes in a shirt.

Here are a couple pics I found online:
[image: darn with patch]you can see that this was machine sewn.

[image: machine darn] this is machine sewn and is a great example of how nicely you can darn a hole so it is not visible. Notice the sewing foot that was used due to the hole being so near the seam.

***As a doting customer for more than a decade**, Diamond Gusset Jeans are worth the investment. The main reason this falls under this topic, is the design. All of their jeans (including women's) have the gusset in the crotch. This design along with the quality of denim make for years of daily wear. My husband still wears his first pair and he wears jeans every day. They are no longer black, more like charcoal grey, but, no holes in the knees or crotch. On the other hand, my jeans have begun to wear in the crotch seam this past year, but as a curved woman whose shorts and pants have always worn first at the crotch, they surpass my expectations.

Comment: Generally, naming brands as long as you disclose your relation with the company (doting customer) is fine, particularly if you explain well **why** you find their product to be preferred. That being said, I'm not sure that naming a brand on this question is appropriate and may be better served as a comment as "What brand of jeans doesn't thin at the crotch" is not an on-topic question here. Answers should focus on how to fix the pants rather than which brand of pants don't have the problem.

Comment: As I do agree with Catija, it would still be nice to know which brand you suggest.